# TinyMCE : setContent insert the whole content in a P tag in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce

I'm trying to make some web pages editable through a backoffice interface and I'm using TinyMCE 4.7.9. I'm not making the whole page editable, instead I just retrieve a part (an HTML code) that I insert in the TinyMCE area with the **setContent** method.

It works fine in Firefox but with Chrome, the content is inserted in a p tag. So instead of having an HTML rendered, we just see the HTML code raw.

I've tried to add :

```
force_br_newlines : false
force_p_newlines : false
forced_root_block : ''
```

But nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you use http://fiddle.tinymce.com/ to create an example setup for TinyMCE that shows this behavior in action?

Comment: I found the problem while I was trying to set a fiddle for the example. In fact, I was storing the content to be set in a noscript tag that I was retrieving then with the innerHTML method. I don't even know why I did this. I just changed to a div and the problem was solved. So it wasn't a TinyMCE issue.